# problem with "&" sign when using ajax to post data to php

Tags: php, ajax, post, ampersand

i use tinyMce as my editor.
everything is fine with sending content to save in database or echo it out. but when an ampersand sign  "&" comes , all data after that truncated and dont save in database or echo out
what should i do. here i have file , it's only 1kb, please download it, run it
thank you everyone.

[**Download File**](http://www.parsgamers.com/downloads/2files.rar)

please if you could fine a way to get rid of "&" sign tell me and others how... .

Comment: Could you please post the relevant section of your code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is surely in the js. you should use encodeURIComponent() to send urlencoded information. as in

```
var parameters = 'message='+encodeURIComponent(message);
```

[encodeURIComponent() on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: God! I thought I was never going to find a solution for this tinyMCE, &amp; and AJAX POST issue. Thanks Einacio.

Comment: you save my day. I've used firstly encodeURI(), then escape(), with odds results, encodeURIComponent() is the way.