# Getting tinymce contents stops when a special character is encountered

Tags: php, tinymce

I can't figure out why my php processing script stops when it encounters a special character in a tinymce textarea.
example if I type foo and submit, fine...no problems but if I type foo<<<, it stops after foo when I submit
the editor is creating the html entities and sending them through ajax

getting the content with

```
var c = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent();
```

and sending the content

```
ajax.send("action=edit_content&c="+c+"&id="+id);
```

and I can see in firebug that the string is being passed

```
action=edit_content&c=<p>foo &lt;&lt;&lt;</p>&id=8
```

and the php is really nothing special at all, just set that post  to a var

is it maybe because of the & in the `&lt;` ? maybe it thinks that is actually another post parameter?

I am still getting my feet wet when it comes to ajax. If I am correct on my assumption, how do I fix that?

Comment: Yes, possibly. Show `QUERY_STRING` and `$_GET`. Utilize POST instead, or [url encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea.  The ampersand is breaking the URL string.

In order to fix breaking characters, you have to `escape` the string.

Try this:

```
ajax.send("action=edit_content&c="+escape(c)+"&id="+id);
```

You probably won't have to (because Apache will do it for you), but if necessary, you can also unescape the string on the PHP side using `urldecode`:

```
<?php echo urldecode($_GET['c']); ?>
```

Comment: awesome !! now that works, but I see that it also adds quite a bit to the markup. would I be better off to maybe set up a regex before I send it so it finds all those and replace them with something else then have php replace that back again after processing and before putting it into the database

Comment: No.  That's what `escape` does - it replaces special characters with pre-defined url-safe strings.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use the system that everyone else does.

Comment: look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986742/problem-with-sign-when-using-ajax-to-post-data-to-php
for another possible solution, escape() in my case transform "too much" the string.